# Cancel AsyncTask by clickig on Notification

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask

I have an activity where I load different fragment with navigation drawer options.

Those fragments have different asynctasks (e.g. one for downloading image, one for importing for database etc.). Every time an asynctask is initiated, I use NotificationManager to show the progress.

What I am looking for is, if anybody click on any notification, it will cancel corresponding AsyncTask. I read about PendingIntent method, but I am not sure whether I need to open an intent to do that.

Also, I am confused how to get reference of the AsyncTasks from my MainActivity as they are initiated inside fragment (and those fragments get destroyed time to time).

I can put some code here if you want, but the code is very basic AsyncTask and Fragment based Navigation Drawer with single Activity.

Thanks,

```
public class MyFragment1 extends Fragment {
    private DownloadFile asynctaskhandler;
    public method(){
        asynctaskhandler = new DownloadFile();
        asynctaskhandler.execute();
    }
    private class DownloadFile extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Void> {
        NotificationManager mNotifyManager;
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder;
        int mId;
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... args) {
            while(){
                //DON SOMETHING, GET PROGRESS progress
                mBuilder.setProgress(mId, progress, true);
                mNotifyManager.notify(mId, mBuilder.build());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: an example for cancelling an asynctask http://www.quicktips.in/correct-way-to-cancel-an-asynctask-in-android/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To many questions in this one... I'll try to answer the one about notification.

notification:

```
        Intent intent2 = new Intent();
        intent2.setAction("com.app.example.MyServiceClass.STOP");
        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent2, 0);

        noti = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setContentTitle("Recorder")
                .setContentText("running")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                .addAction(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Stop", pIntent)
                .build();

        startForeground(12345, noti);
```

Service (receiver of the pendingIntent):

```
 // registering BroadcastReceiver
    IntentFilter filter2 = new IntentFilter();
    filter2.addAction("com.app.example.MyServiceClass.STOP"); //further more
    registerReceiver(receiver, filter2);


private final BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();

        if(action.equals("com.app.example.MyServiceClass.STOP")){
            isCancelled = true;  // this is a class variable
            sendMessage("hide");
        }

    }
};
```

doInBackground:

```
 protected Boolean doInBackground(String... StringUrls) {
  // some loop

      if (myServiceClass.this.isCancelled)  {

         myServiceClass.this.stopSelf();

      }

   // some loop
 }
```

Comment: thanks for reply, i am reading it now :) ... just for clarification, all I want is some means to cancel the AsyncTask from notification ... :)

Comment: Ok, so this should do the job. I took it from the working code.

Comment: sorry, because I am new and never worked with service, if u kindly clarify .. where exactly should I put the codes "Service (receiver of the pendingIntent)"?

Comment: It depends on your Service implementation but generally "registration of the BroadcastRegister" goes inside Service's `onStartCommand()` and the "receiver" itself goes anywhere inside `Service { }`.